# Find code coverage of ApexClass before deployment

Tags: apex, deployment, code-coverage, tooling-api

I want to find ApexClass code coverage before deployment. Is there any way to get the code coverage using tooling API.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Why do you not just check in the `Developer Console` or through the UI? There are a lot of ways to check current coverage...

Answer (score 1):

This will help you get started in the right direction.

[Checking Code Coverage](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&type=0)

[Reliable ways to calculate Overall Code Coverage in salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199478&type=1)

[SOQL to find code coverage in Salesforce](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/06/soql-to-find-code-coverage-in-salesforce.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My scenario is I want the code coverage of an apex class before deployment to the target environment.
For ex. If I use ApexCodeCoverage or ApexCodeCoverageAggregate and test in dev environment, I get the code coverage of a particular class but if I deploy that class to target environment the code coverage of that class might be different so is there any option in tooling API to validate the CodeCoverage in both the Environment.(Ex. CheckOnly )

Answer (score 0):

The Tooling API gives you three resources for monitoring code coverage:

1. [ApexCodeCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverage.htm)

   > Represents code coverage test results for an Apex class or trigger.
2. [ApexCodeCoverageAggregate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverageaggregate.htm)

   > Represents aggregate code coverage test results for an Apex class or trigger.
3. [ApexOrgWideCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexorgwidecoverage.htm)

   > Represents code coverage test results for an entire organization.

You will likely want `ApexCodeCoverageAggregate` filtered by the ApexClassorTriggerId. It will give you the high level `NumLinesCovered` and `NumLinesUncovered` plus the detailed `Coverage` field.